# typescript variable with different values

Tags: typescript, function

I'm using TypeScript with ES6

Take a look at the following code:

```
    private latestPrices: any = {};

    public constructor() {
        this.timer = global.setInterval(this.getPricesCallback, 1500);
    }

    private getPricesCallback() {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
        console.log("Hello");

        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
        console.log(this.latestPrices);

        this.latestPrices = { "bookname ":"VB BLACK BOOK", "price":500 };

        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
        console.log(this.latestPrices);
    }

    public getLatestPrices()
    {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
        console.log(this.latestPrices);
        return this.latestPrices;
    }
```

The Output is:

```
Hello
{ "bookname ":"VB BLACK BOOK", "price":500 }
{ "bookname ":"VB BLACK BOOK", "price":500 }
```

And this every 1.5 seconds... So far so good. But every time I call "getLatestPrices" I only get:

```
{}
```

Why is this?
I don't see the problem right now.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a classic js pitfall with the scoping.
`this` argument inside `getPricesCallback` points to another context when called back by setinterval, so it sets `lastPrices` property there.

changing `global.setInterval(this.getPricesCallback, 1500);`

to `global.setInterval(this.getPricesCallback.bind(this), 1500);`

or `global.setInterval(() => this.getPricesCallback(), 1500);`

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks!!! global.setInterval(this.getPricesCallback.bind(this), 1500); did the trick!